# Error al usar Dos modelos en una vista- mvc core

Tags: asp.net-core, view, model

I have a model for Musico and another for Commune,
I try to bring both of them this way ..
I tried to use ** Tuple ** among other things but I went back to the base which was this

[mi error..](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pbFu1.png)

```
public class ComunaViewModel
  {
    public Comuna ComunaDTO { get; set; }
    public Musico MusicoDTO { get; set; }
  }
```

musico

```
public class Musico
  {
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Nombre { get; set; }
    public string Estilos { get; set; }
    public int IdComuna { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
```

Comuna

```
public class Comuna
  {
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Nombre { get; set; }
```

--

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
      return View(await _context.Musico.ToListAsync());

    }
```

view

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.MusicoDTO.Nombre)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.MusicoDTO.Estilos)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ComunaDTO.Nombre)
----
@foreach (var item in Model) {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.MusicoDTO.Nombre)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.MusicoDTO.Estilos)
             </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ComunaDTO.Nombre)
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not in English - please try [es.so]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass `List<ComunaViewModel>` rather than `List<Musico>` to your view.
You can try to convert `List<Musico>` to `List<ComunaViewModel>`.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
       List<Musico> l = await _context.Musico.ToListAsync();
       List<ComunaViewModel> l1 = new List<ComunaViewModel>();
       foreach (var item in l)
       {
           l1.Add(new ComunaViewModel { MusicoDTO = item });
       }
      return View(l1);

    }
```